# Hardening evaluation of shared objects files

Tags: hardening

In order to evaluate if security mechanisms are applied on binary files during compilation I usually use the checksec tool.

My question is: if I want to check an .so file, which checksec's fields should I consider?

I'll try to explain me better.

I'm not really sure if the same security mechanisms considered for an executable can be used for a shared object.

For example the PIE field cannot be considered because a shared object is (by definition) already position-independent (and usually an .so is  marked as DSO).

I think the remaining parameters (NX, Fortify, stack, relro, rpath, runpath) shall be considered in a .so file too, but I'm not really sure.